# text not displaying when using event-set-component and template- component

Tags: aframe, webvr

i am making webvr with multiple scenes using [A-frame template](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/template) component and [event set component](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/event-set) to listen for mouseenter/click so it'll change my src.

[Here's](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/test-multiple) the full example code in glitch and below is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Kingdom Animalia</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Belajar asyik dengan WebVR"></meta>
    <script src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a40a8a20-2b6c-4579-a653-7b641753965e%2Fbuild.js?1531824946222"></script>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="aframe-event-set-component.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <a-scene>

     <a-assets>
        <img id="cnidaria" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/1f690faa-4dea-4828-a14a-c8fc529e9e2d%2F492542401-56a5f70d5f9b58b7d0df4ff5.jpg?1531237316164">
        <img id="porifera" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/1f690faa-4dea-4828-a14a-c8fc529e9e2d%2FPHYLUM%20PORIFERA%20_thumb%5B6%5D.jpg?1531237318597">
        <img id="annelida" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/1f690faa-4dea-4828-a14a-c8fc529e9e2d%2Fearthworm.jpg?1531237319615">
        <img id="planaria" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/1f690faa-4dea-4828-a14a-c8fc529e9e2d%2Fmaxresdefault.jpg?1531237360227">
        <img id="mollusca" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/1f690faa-4dea-4828-a14a-c8fc529e9e2d%2F802806388.jpg?1531237319128">
        <img id="ctenophora" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/1f690faa-4dea-4828-a14a-c8fc529e9e2d%2FRedLine1.jpg?1531237316608">
      </a-assets>

      <a-entity id="ganti" template="src: main.html"
                position="0 0 0">
      </a-entity>


      <a-sky id="mask" color="#111" opacity="0" radius="2">
        <a-animation attribute="material.opacity" begin="fade" from="0" to="1" dur="200"
                     direction="alternate" repeat="1"></a-animation>
      </a-sky>
    </a-scene>


  </body>
</html>
```

below the main.html

```
 <a-entity
        position="-1 3 -3"
        geometry="primitive: plane; width: 8; height: auto"
        material="color: #0000FF"
        text="color: white; align: center; font: https://cdn.aframe.io/fonts/DejaVu-sdf.fnt;
              value: a-plane align:center (anchor:align) DejaVu width 8 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890">
      </a-entity>

      <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9" shadow></a-box>
      <a-sphere 
      event-set__click="_target: #ganti; template: src: boxes.html" 
      position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#000000" shadow></a-sphere>
      <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D" shadow></a-cylinder>
      <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4" shadow></a-plane>
      <a-sky color="#c69b9b"></a-sky>


    <a-camera>
        <a-cursor id="cursor" position="0 0 0" color= "#efdf02"></a-cursor>
      </a-camera>
```

so far i can display img, boxes, spheres etc on the scenes, but it doesnt show any text at all. i've tried a lot of different kind of text. Text still showing up in other code which not using the template & event set component, but in my example it won't display. how can i fix this?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code.  Don't post links to code.

Comment: @TheWhiteWolf i've edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your includes are wrong, first you include the `template` component, then the `core`, then the `event` component.

If the core is loaded first, then the text is being displayed on the `a-plane`

Check it out [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/jealous-dresser?path=main.html:3:44)

Comment: it did work, thanks! but the event set doesn't work anymore?

Comment: check it out now, the "mask" with a width of 2 was intercepting the click events

Comment: thanks a lot!! it did work! i have no idea the mask was the problem!